# Keras 2.2.4 runs slowly with backend cntk-gpu version 2.5.1

Tags: keras, gpu, cntk

everyone. I have a problem when I use Keras with backend cntk-gpu version 2.5.1.

For some reason, I have to use cntk-gpu 2.5.1 as Keras backend and I have a piece of code with the core code as follows (really simple code for prediction):

```
# test_x: test data from dataset imagenet
predict_model = keras.models.load_model(model_path,custom_objects=ModelUtils.custom_objects())
predict_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
res = predict_model.predict(test_x,batch_size=4)
```

I found that the cntk-gpu2.7 version only takes 50 seconds, but the version 2.5.1 takes 20 minutes. The console shows that cntk does use gpu because it prints my GPU information like:

> Selected GPU[0] GeForce GTX 1080 Ti as the process wide default device

I have tested both on ubuntu18.04 cuda10.0 and ubuntu16.04 cuda9.1. Version 2.4 and below will also encounter this problem

I don't know what the reason is and how to solve the problem.
Have you ever encountered a situation where the cntk-gpu 2.5 version is running very slowly?

I hope to hear from you. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I lost `Hi` when I was pasting the problem. Sorry.

Comment: The model I use is xception which is pre-trained by keras